# Remove site name from title post

Tags: title, seo

I want to remove the site-name from title post and used All in One SEO and this is the configuration

[image]

but in Google search the site name display in all title post ( as this )

[image]

How can I remove sitename from title post?

Answer (score 5):

Check your theme (`header.php`). If it uses something like this :

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

You can use this filter :

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse104667_wp_title' );
function wpse104667_wp_title( $title ) {

    global $post;
    if(
       is_singular() 
       && !is_front_page() 
       && !is_home() 
       && !is_404() 
       && !is_tag()
     )
    $new_title = get_the_title($post->ID) ;
    return $new_title;
}
```

**EDIT: add conditional tags to avoid bad conflicts**

Comment: please where i put this code

Comment: in a file called `functions.php`

Comment: but found problem when i click on categories .  its remove categories name and display the first post title alternate categories name

Comment: true ! missed that, I'm editing

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is not caused by your theme, then you are doing this right.

Now when you set %post_titile% go to any post and check source code. If you get what you want under titile tag, then you are good to go. All you have to do now is to wait for google bot to visit your site and collect new informations from your posts.